# Do any regular expression fiddlers fully support lookbehind?

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

I'm looking to test a regular expression that includes lookbehind with possibly infinite repetition. E.g:

```
(?<!this can't appear anywhere before.*)text to match
```

*This is just an example - the actual regex is nothing like this so please don't answer with alternative ways of doing this!*

According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html, this would be supported by .NET but I couldn't get it to work in any of the regex fiddlers I've tried. Just wondering if anyone has seen this problem or knows of a regex fiddler (ideally online) that uses the .NET framework as its engine?

**EDIT:** At the time of writing this has 3 close votes and some comments below about being off topic. But the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/about) includes "Software development tools" in its tick list of acceptable questions. As the question relates to a fairly advanced regular expression feature I thought it would be best targeted towards the programmer community. Also think it could be of interest to others here so would be worth being recorded as a question rather than a fragment of chatroom conversation. This is just my 2p-worth, am sure there will be those who disagree - but at least please brush up on the rules (e.g. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192821/are-questions-about-software-development-tools-but-not-asking-for-references-o) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61720/where-should-questions-about-software-development-tools-go)) before close-voting.

Comment: The question is off-topic, but one that you can use [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/), although it prevents copy/paste in its online version. Note: I got it though googling.

Comment: Had a feeling this might be voted as off topic. I do find that a bit pedantic though, as there are a huge number of questions on here that discuss regular expressions and a whole lot of their answers use regex fiddler demos. Not sure where such a question would be better placed. Anyway, your answer is good - if you'd care to put it as an answer rather than a comment I'll accept.

Comment: @SteveChambers It really depends what you mean by "discussing regular expressions". I agree that there is a lot of regex questions that should be closed but that doesn't mean we should encourage such posts. Also, the answers usually contains a fiddle to [demonstrate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183552/) that it actually works. If you feel that it may be off-topic, you may always join one of the [SO chatrooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com), in this particular case the [regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767).

Comment: Still think it's debatable whether this is off-topic. The [guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) includes "software tools commonly used by programmers" but later excludes questions asking to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". This question isn't asking for a recommendation but rather asking whether a tool exists with a particularly rare feature. (This shouldn't necessarily attract opinionated answers as more than one tool could be listed if they existed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that this question is off-topic for SO. It might be better suited for superuser.com, a sister site of SO.

Otherwise, one site you can use is [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/). Not as userfriendly as some other online regex testers as you cannot quickly copy from there and it frequently bugs you for buying it, but the primary purpose is available.